# Parameter value [%Gabrek%] did not match expected type [java.lang.Character (n/a)];

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp, jpa

i've been writing wirting a program in Spring Boot Web with JPA and i'm using a query to access some data with a 'contains' and 'ignorecase' filter, i've done this before in other programs and it has worked fine, but now i'm getting this error, i'm completely lost at this point since i can't find anything in google, i went really far down the rabbit hole looking as to why it happens and so far i don't see anything out of place in my code, the type of variable declared seems to be okay but as i've said, i'm lost. It's important to mention that for some reason when I do the query on my website for the first time, everything works fine, i get the proper results and all, but when I go back to home and try with another query (or even the same) i get the error. Code below:

**Model**

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Serie {
    
    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "NUMERIC(19,0)")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private String red;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "NUMERIC(19,0)")
    private double rating;
```

**Repository**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import cl.desafiolatam.imdb.modelo.Serie;

public interface SerieRepository extends JpaRepository<Serie, Integer> {

    public List<Serie> findByTitleContainingIgnoreCase(String title);
    
}
```

**Service**

```
import cl.desafiolatam.imdb.vo.SerieVO;

public interface SerieService {
    
    public SerieVO findByTitleContainingIgnoreCase(String title);

}
```

**Service implementation**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import cl.desafiolatam.imdb.dao.SerieRepository;
import cl.desafiolatam.imdb.modelo.Serie;
import cl.desafiolatam.imdb.service.SerieService;
import cl.desafiolatam.imdb.vo.SerieVO;

@Service
public class SerieServiceImpl implements SerieService {
    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SerieServiceImpl.class);
    
    @Autowired
    SerieRepository dao;
    SerieVO respuesta;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public SerieVO findByTitleContainingIgnoreCase(String title) {
        
        respuesta = new SerieVO("Ha ocurrido un error!", "104", new ArrayList<Serie>());

        try {
            List<Serie> serie = dao.findByTitleContainingIgnoreCase(title);
            System.out.println(serie);
            if(serie.size() > 0) {
                respuesta.setSeries(serie);
                respuesta.setMensaje("Se ha encontrado el registro");
                respuesta.setCodigo("0");
            } else {
                respuesta.setMensaje("No se ha encontrado el registro");
                respuesta.setCodigo("104");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error al buscar la serie", e);
        }
        
        return respuesta;
    }

}
```

**Visual object**

```
import java.util.List;

import cl.desafiolatam.imdb.modelo.Serie;

public class SerieVO extends GenericVO {
    
    List<Serie> series;

    public SerieVO(String mensaje, String codigo, List<Serie> series) {
        super(mensaje, codigo);
        this.series = series;
    }

    public SerieVO() {
        super();
    }
```

**Controller**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import cl.desafiolatam.imdb.modelo.Serie;
import cl.desafiolatam.imdb.service.SerieService;
import cl.desafiolatam.imdb.vo.SerieVO;

@Controller
public class SerieController {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SerieController.class);

    @Autowired
    private SerieService svc;

@GetMapping("/buscarSerie")
    public ModelAndView buscarSerie(Model model, @RequestParam String nombreSerie) {
        
        SerieVO respuestaServicio = new SerieVO();
        respuestaServicio.setMensaje("No se ha encontrado la serie");
        
        try {
            respuestaServicio = svc.findByTitleContainingIgnoreCase(nombreSerie);
            model.addAttribute("listaSeries", respuestaServicio.getSeries());
            return new ModelAndView("resultadoserie");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error al buscar la serie", e);
        }
        
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/user");
        
    }
}
```

**Search input**

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center pb-2">
        <div class="container row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <h2>Buscar serie</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <form action="buscarSerie" method="get">
                    <div class="row g-2">
                        <div class="col-md">
                            <div class="form-floating">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInputGrid"
                                    value="" name="nombreSerie" required> <label
                                    for="floatingInputGrid">Serie</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center pt-4">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn m-2 btn-dark" value="Buscar" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As i've said, im really lost, researched everywhere, and checked the code in my last projects, i just can't find out why this one does me this dirty. Won't even fail at the start, it gives me a glimpse of hope and when i want to retry it, it crushes that little hope. :)

I tried deleting my code and copy&paste from projects where i know it works as intended, changed the variable and param. names to make it work with the new program but didn't work. Did a side by side comparison, tried a @Query writing the specific instruction. Looking for info. only with the 'contains' filter and yet, nothing worked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the Spring Data JPA [issue #2472](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2472) this seems to be a problem in Hibernate 5.6.6 and 5.6.7.

The Hibernate bug is [HHH-15142](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15142).

The solution is to either downgrade to Hibernate 5.6.5 or wait for a Hibernate patch to solve this issue.

**Update**: According to the bug report above this is resolved in version 5.6.9.

Comment: Thank you! i remember reading something like this yesterday but i was so obfuscated that it went right over my head.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same bug and I tried to Extract JPQL query like that

```
@Query("select u from user u where upper(u.name) like upper(?1)")
List<User> findByNameLikeIgnoreCase(final String pName) ;
```

and it's worked in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Try using @Param annotation:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import cl.desafiolatam.imdb.modelo.Serie;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

public interface SerieRepository extends JpaRepository<Serie, Integer> {   
    public List<Serie> findByTitleContainingIgnoreCase(@Param(title) String title);
}
```

Solution from this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2472)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem too. First the web app would run initially and consequently return type errors Parameter value [%ben%] did not match expected type [java.lang.Character (n/a)];. Downgrading the hibernate verion in pom.xml to 5.6.5.Final helped and it works well now

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```